# Implementing IEnumerable<T> interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

As per my understanding based on Microsoft's documentation. When you implement [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8) interface you are forced to implement [IEnumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1?view=netframework-4.8) as well. Which as per my understanding means I need to provide a definition for methods such as `MoveNext()`, Reset() and property `current{get;}`

But I have come across this snippet which does not fit my understanding:

```
    class Option<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        private IEnumerable<T> Content { get; }

        private Option(IEnumerable<T> content)
        {
            this.Content = content;
        }

        public static Option<T> Some(T value) => new Option<T>(new[] {value});
        public static Option<T> None() => new Option<T>(new T[0]);

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => this.Content.GetEnumerator(); //Need explanation
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => this.GetEnumerator();//Need explanation
    }
```

What does `this.Content.GetEnumerator();` and `this.GetEnumerator();` do here?
There is no implementation of `MoveNext()` or `Reset()` or `current`.

Also I am unable to understand what are the above two lines of code doing?

Comment: IEnumerable have only 1 method which is `GetEnumerator()` which you have to implement. You don't need to implement IEnumerator as well. You can use a simple for/foreach which implements IEnumerator on their own. **Edit** even in the link you gave `StreamReaderEnumerable` only implements `GetEnumerator()`

Comment: @styx Ok so I need to only implement `GetEnumerator()`. But I am still confused about `this.Content.GetEnumerator();` and `this.GetEnumerator();` 
One method is for generic another for non generic. And What exactly happens when I do `this.Content.GetEnumerator(); `  Returns an Enumerator? How? .NET framework handles it internally? On its own? I am not able to wrap my head around why these methods have to be implemented. How does it fit in the big picture. Sorry for sounding like a noob. But this is getting frustrating for me.

Comment: I mean you **do** have to implement `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()` and not the ` IEnumerator`  interface(therefore no need for moveNext, etc). you have to implement to because `IEnumerable` exposes `IEnumerator`, To elaborate a little more, `IEnumerable` exposes a method `GetEnumerator`. This method returns an `IEnumerator` so you can then use it to perform the enumerating. Also, you can't do `this.Content = content`; because you made `Content` read-only

Comment: @styx ok that made things a little but clearer. 
You said that `IEnumerable exposes a method GetEnumerator` isn't IEnumerable just an interface? It could not contain any definition of any methods. So, if I say `private IEnumerable<T> Content { get; }` I am not using a class that uses IEnumerable but the interface itself. So where does the definition for `GetEnumerator` on `IEnumerable` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does `this.Content.GetEnumerator();` and `this.GetEnumerator();` do here?

First method returns generic `IEnumerator<T>`, second one returns non-generic variant using explicit implementation of `IEnumerable` interface (actually, `IEnumerator<T>` inherits non-generic `IEnumerator`, as you can see in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1?view=netframework-4.8))

`Current` property is declared in generic `IEnumerator<T>`, `MoveNext()` and `Reset()` are declared in non-generic `IEnumerator`.

`IEnumerable` exposes `IEnumerator` struct to iterate through collection, this a reason of separating the methods.

First versions of .NET have only non-generic collections, generics were introduced later, so there is both generic and non-generic variants of `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`.

You can refer to [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,d3661cf752ff3f44) to see, how it's implemented internally for generic `List<T>`.

```cs
internal Enumerator(List<T> list) {
    this.list = list;
    index = 0;
    version = list._version;
    current = default(T);
}
```

Actually the list instance is passed to `Enumerator` constructor and `MoveNext()`, `Reset()` and `Current` are working over the passed instance

Comment: if I say `private IEnumerable<T> Content { get; }` I am not using a class that uses `IEnumerable` but the interface itself. So where does the definition for `GetEnumerator `on `IEnumerable` come from?

Comment: It comes from `IEnumerable<T>` implementation

Comment: Sorry, still not getting it. What you mean by `It comes from IEnumerable<T> inheritance`. It's not like I have `private List<T> Content { get; }` where List inherits from IEnumerable and List is responsible for providing definition for `GetEnumerator()`

Comment: In your class `Option<T>` you are implementing `IEnumerable<T>` interface. Bo methods for getting a generic and non generic `IEnumerator` must be implemented. You are passing `content` to `Option` ctor, what will be under the hood depending on type of collection, which you've passed

Comment: Yes which is why we have the last two lines in the snippet. Both the `GetEnumerator` method have been implemented for class Option. What do they do? It calls `GetEnumerator()` on    `IEnumerable<T> Content`. 

 Where is the definition/impementation of `GetEnumerator()` of Content? 

Is it provided by the compiler when it sees `GetEnumerator()` on `IEnumerable`?

Comment: oh! I just realized that I can not write IEnumerable list = new IEnumerable()  I will have to write  IEnumerable list = new List(); That means List class will provide the implementation for GetEnumerator?

Comment: Yes, exactly, you can't create an instance of `IEnumerable` or `Enumerable`, you can create only an instance of collection, implementing an `IEnumerable`

Comment: It was simpler than I had thought. I apologize for taking so much of your time to understand something so simple. Thanks for being patient with me.